# Unable to submit app on appstore testflight Xcode-Version 9 Beta

Tags: ios, testflight, xcode9-beta

I am trying deploy my first release on test fight.But getting this error.I am using VM of mac OS 10.12 and Xcode 9 beta version.
Its strange that same VM and Xcode is deploying release from other machine.
Please guide me how can i remove these error

[image]

Comment: Please read the error description. It clearly says that you can't use beta version to upload apps to AppStore.

Answer (score 2):

The comments saying you can't do this are incorrect. You can't *release to the App Store* with a beta version of Xcode, but you can certainly upload from beta Xcode to TestFlight for versions that support that.

**UPDATE:**
As of 8/30/17, you should build and submit with Xcode 9 beta 6. The previous workaround I had here about building with beta 5 and submitting with beta 6 is no longer needed and no longer works.

Submitting with Xcode 9 beta 6 will give you the normal "successful upload" screen.

Comment: Having the same error with Xcode 9 beta 6. Installing b5 now. Kinda surprised there isn't more online about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You must use the release-build of xcode (xcode 8) and macos sierra. These are the (lastest) public versions.

Comment: Actually I am using some libraries which only available in swift v.4.But how the same beta version submitting other app from other machine

Comment: You can't submit an app to the app store using beta-software.

Comment: You can't release an app to the App Store using beta software, but it has been possible to upload beta builds to TestFlight